# Modal view controller segue from custom cell selection issue - iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, modalviewcontroller

I just recently noticed this issue in my app, and it seems to be an anomaly because I cannot pin down how/why it is happening, and there is no way to predict when. I have a custom `UITableViewCell` that I am loading into my `UITableView` subclass. I only have 5 cells in my `tableView` at all times, they are static and not prototypes. The issue I'm having is that sometime after I dismiss a modal view that I got to my selecting one of the cells, other cells become buggy. Here is what happens:

•Either I touch the cell and it performs the segue as planned

•About 10+ seconds after I touch the cell the segue is performed

•I touch the cell and nothing happens, but if I touch anywhere else on the view, the segue is performed

It is very very similar to the problem posted "[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283097/ios7-issue-with-modal-view-controller-segue-from-custom-cell-selection)" as well.

Here is my code:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        //[super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        //self.selectedObject = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"I DID SELECT path %ld", (long)indexPath.row);
        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

        if(indexPath.row == 0 && self.matchOneSetNum <= 3)
        {
            self.whereFrom = 1;
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"enterScoresSegue" sender:self];
        }

        if(indexPath.row == 1 && self.matchTwoSetNum <= 3)
        {
            self.whereFrom = 2;
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"enterScoresSegue" sender:self];
        }

        if(indexPath.row == 2 && self.matchThreeSetNum <= 3)
        {
            self.whereFrom = 3;
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"enterScoresSegue" sender:self];
        }

        if(indexPath.row == 3 && self.matchFourSetNum <= 3)
        {
            self.whereFrom = 4;
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"enterScoresSegue" sender:self];
        }

        if(indexPath.row == 4 && self.matchFiveSetNum <= 3)
        {
            self.whereFrom = 5;
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"enterScoresSegue" sender:self];
        }


    }

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"enterScoresSegue"])
    {
        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        UINavigationController *newView = (UINavigationController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        EnterScoresViewController *enter = newView.topViewController;
        enter.myDelegate = self;
        enter.otherTeam = self.otherTeam;

        if(self.whereFrom == 1)
        {

            enter.match = self.matchOne;
            enter.setNumber = self.matchOneSetNum;
            enter.matchOnePlayer = self.playerName;
        }

        if(self.whereFrom == 2)
        {

            enter.match = self.matchTwo;
            enter.setNumber = self.matchTwoSetNum;
            enter.matchTwoPlayer = self.playerNameTwo;
        }

        if(self.whereFrom == 3)
        {

            enter.match = self.matchThree;
            enter.setNumber = self.matchThreeSetNum;
            enter.matchThreePlayer = self.playerNameThree;
        }

        if(self.whereFrom == 4)
        {

            enter.match = self.matchFour;
            enter.setNumber = self.matchFourSetNum;
            enter.matchFourPlayers = self.playerStringsFour;
        }

        if(self.whereFrom == 5)
        {

            enter.match = self.matchFive;
            enter.setNumber = self.matchFiveSetNum;
            enter.matchFivePlayers = self.playerStringsFive;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you post some code to help us solve your problem?

Comment: Sure, sorry about that!

Comment: For the future, you might want to take a look at [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more tips on how to ask great questions.

Comment: Alright, I posted my code. And, thanks, I will take a look at that for future questions...

Comment: Are your segues connected from the cells, or from the controller?

Comment: They are from the tableviewcontroller in the storyboard

Comment: There's nothing in the code you show that should cause this problem.  It's going to be hard to diagnose this without actually trying out the app. Can you upload the project somewhere?

Comment: I'd rather not as it is a completed app...

Comment: Good luck then. You should post the solution yourself if you find one, so other people can learn from whatever this problem turns out to be.

Comment: @rdelmar If you go to the question I linked to above, there is a sample app that has the problem...

Comment: That sample app is no longer available. I've asked the poster of that question if he can re-upload it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an answer on a similar question that fixed the issue for me, here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23747207/2584268

And here is the full text:

After filling a Radar Apple responded with adding:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{});
```

To the end of the following method, which does the trick:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

> In the method that presents the controller, you can schedule a no-op
>   block which will force the runloop to spin and there will be no delay.

Radar Ref: 15196237, feel free to file another and reference this.

Answer (score 0):

wendrring  if you segue in storyboard from a cell or from the ViewController(sender is self in this case), if from a cell the sender should be a cell too.

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"enterScoresSegue" sender:[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

Comment: The segue is from the view controller